# How to create a new JIRA issue when jenkins job failed

Tags: jenkins, jira

I can able to create the new issue in Jira using this ("**JIRA Pipeline steps**") plugin in the pipeline script.

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    def server = "cloudjira"

    def testIssue = [fields: [ project: [id: '10000'],
                                 summary: 'Issue created from Jenkins.',
                                 description: 'Created from Jenkins.',
                                 issuetype: [id: '10001']]]

      response = jiraNewIssue issue: testIssue, site: 'server'

      echo response.successful.toString()
      echo response.data.toString()
      
    }
}
```

**But I need to create a new issue based on the Jenkins job status.**

**Requirements:**

1. If the current job failed, check if the issue was already created. If yes, adds a comment, if not, create a new JIRA issue.
2. If the current job passed, check if the issue from (point 1) is Closed or Done.
   If not, adds a comment.
3. And if the issue is not fixed and the job
   has failed again- It will add the comment on the existing Jira
   issue.

- Jenkins running in my local environment. Jenkins version: 2.319.3
- Jira running on the cloud instance.

Is there any other plugin to achieve the above requirements or any different approach?

I am Requesting your help to resolve this issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

Using "Post-build Actions" of Jenkins. An easy [step-by-step guide](https://devopsbuzz.com/create-jira-issue-on-build-failure-through-jenkins/) to follow is here.

For summary:

- Install Jira plugin in Jenkins: download and install through Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins
- Go to Configure system and fill your Jira site details
- Open your Jenkins project
- Click on Post build actions
- Choose “Create Jira issue”
- Fill the details accordingly.
- Then select the Action Id

The page also said that it was tested for cases:

> You can create a JIRA issue in the project with the given Jira project key.
>
> If current build failed, checks if issue was already created. If yes, adds a comment, if not, creates a new JIRA issue.
>
> If current build passed, checks if issue from p.1 is Closed or Done. If not, adds a comment.
>
> And if the issue is not fixed and build has failed again- It will add the comment on existing jira issue.

Comment: I have tried with your answer. I am facing the issue: "Build step 'Jira: Create issue' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE".  Do I need any privileges for that Jira account? because currently, I am just a Jira user (not admin roles). Also configured the Jira in Jenkins using an API token.